# How many signers can we have on a single document in docusign

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

How many signers can we have on a single document in DocuSign? For Ex - Currently, we have two signer
1) Student
2) Teacher

Now we want the third signer as Principal. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, envelopes can support three signers.